# DNS NAmeserver Aname and cname records

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I am inexperienced in the configuration of DNS and have an issue with domain configuration.

I have two domains `www.mydomain1.com` and `www.mydomain2.com`, with mydomain2 pointed at the same place as mydomain1.

The domains were passed to me recently by the person who previously controlled them. I have an account with fasthosts in the UK. When I accepted the domains I could not access the DNS settings and enquired with fasthosts as to why. The replied saying

> The delegate hosting option for both
>   domains were enabled and this is the
>   reason why you were unable to find the
>   option to edit the advanced DNS
>   records.
>
> I have now disabled the delegate
>   hosting option so you can now edit the
>   advanced DNS records for both domains
>   in your account.

When I log into the fasthost control panel now I can access the DNS controls but both domains have no A Record of CNAME record set up. I am concerned that fasthosts have blatted the previous Nameserver entries and set me up on theirs but not added any records. The domain `www.mydomain1.com` currently still works but `www.mydomain2.com` does not find the site anymore. i am worried I will lose mydomain1 to as the DNS changes filter through the system.

My webhosting is at `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mydomain1.com/` and this is where I want both domains to point. Any advice would be much appreciated.  Oone thing which is confusing me is that because I am on a shared server I have to put `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mydomain1.com/` to get to my site rather than just 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'. The form on fasthosts for the A records only allows an IP to be entered, does it add the mydomain1.com/ onto the end itself?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you control the domain it can be empty (have no entries at all) and you won't loose it, so you can just enter the entries again.

What will not work is to reach your site with just entering www.mydomain{1|2}.com in your situation unless the provider who really hosts your webserver helps you out. All you can do with DNS is to let www.mydomain1.com point to your "xx.xx.xx.xx" IP address, the rest of the web address is part of the HTTP protocol and has nothing to do with DNS.

Your hosting provider can help you by configuring his server to show the content of 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mydomain1.com/' when asked for www.mydomain{1|2}.com, but it's his decision if he wants to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an account with fasthosts in the UK. When I accepted the domains I could not access the DNS settings

Apparently, when the DNS names where transfered to you they where still delegated to some other server for the zone.  If you don't have a copy of the zone database or records that information may be gone, but it may still exist on the old DNS servers.  If you know who used to be providing the DNS servers you may want to ask them if they can send you a backup in some form or another.

If you can't get a backup you are going to have to start manually re-creating your records.

> A records only allows an IP to be entered

The form on an DNS site better do the same thing.  An A record maps an name to an IP address and doesn't do anything else.